# Problem with import raster package: Unable to load module "spmod"

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have installed R (3.5.1) and R-studio (1.1.456) just now (using Anaconda). Then, I installed the raster package (2.9-5). Everything was okay, but when I tried to import, I got this message:

```
> library(raster)
```

> Download required package: sp Error: package or namespace load failed
>   for ‘raster’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):  error in load action
>   .__ A __.1 for package raster: loadModule(module = "spmod", what = TRUE,
>   env = ns, loadNow = TRUE): Unable to load module "spmod": cannot
>   allocate vector of size 15759.3 Gb

**Edit**: The problem actual only windows 10. I tried it on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and everything is okay

Comment: I have the same problem now after upgrading raster, sp and rgdal :-/

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error, also using Windows 10 (R v 3.6.1 and raster v 3.0-7) and was able to solve it by installing the R package ‘Rcpp’.

edit: You can install the R package 'Rcpp' by typing "install.packages("Rcpp")" into the R console. (for more on installing R packages see the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.1/topics/install.packages)

Comment: I might be helpful here for the person who asked the question if you also added how you installed Rcpp